# How to avoid app kill between switching the app in Marshmallow OS

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using payment activity in my android app by using redirection method to web page.

After fill credit card detail if I open message app for see the OTP,
and then again I reopen my app for fill OTP, then I got my webpage again restart from start with credit card detail form...

Problem occurs with Marshmallow only. Working fine in less than android OS 6.

How can I stop refreshing activity?